# Keeping a DHTML tree expanded in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-apex

I have created a list item to be used as the primary navigation within my APEX application.

The tree can be expanded and clicking on a leaf node takes you to the correct page. However, on arrival at the new page, the tree is back at its starting position, completely collapsed. How do I keep the tree expanded?

I am using Apex 3.2.1, the region has been created on page zero. Within the region definition, under the source heading, the value for "List Template Override" is DHTML tree.

Comment: Which Apex theme are you using?

Comment: @Tony, it's a custom one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the DHMTL tree in Apex gives you this option. You can probably achieve it using javascript, although a javascript library solution may be easier - e.g. [ExtJS navigation tree](http://apex.oracle.com/pls/otn/f?p=65555:38:2219147723798078).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the useful link. I haven't worked out a way to do this using what I have already so I have changed the control from a list to a tree. Thanks again.